# how to retrieve data from google book api url?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-api

I wan to retrieve the title, authors from `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780439023528` in javascript and the result display in HTML.

HTML:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function getBookDetails(isbn) {
        isbn = "9780439023528"; 
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:" + isbn;
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        var results = JSON.parse(response);

       if (results.totalItems) {
           var book = results.items[0];
           var title = (book["volumeInfo"]["title"]);
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = book; 
       }   
    }
});
```

Comment: This url not redirect correctly

Comment: I add some code sir

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780439023528 this url is not working

Comment: what do you mean its not working? so its impossible to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

UrlFetchApp class is NOT available in client-side javascript, which is what it looks like you are trying to do. You can only use it in server-side Google Apps Script .gs files.

You can however use XMLHttpRequest to fix your problem.

```
function getBookDetails(isbn) {
    isbn = "9780439023528"; 
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:" + isbn;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var x = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            callback(x);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function callback(x) {
    //do things with your data here
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: how to display book title?